# What's the difference between dynamic and static parameters in Sqlmap?

Tags: sql-injection, databases, sqlmap

What are the practical differences between them? i.e. a parameter referred to as being "dynamic" and "not dynamic"?

Comment: do you mean "--skip-static   Skip testing parameters that not appear dynamic"?

Comment: or the message "testing if POST parameter 'foo' is dynamic"

Comment: This is not well explained nor is it easy to look up online.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites are designed with URL parameters that are hard-coded. There is only one value that will work in that parameter for that session or that request. If you change it in any way, the request will fail or nothing will happen. Static parameters are not injectable (typically), so they are not interesting to sqlmap.

So, it hunts for parameters that it thinks are "dynamic", and therefore, more likely to be injectable.

Any parameter that receives user input is dynamic. Static parameters are those where a value is passed between server and client, and the value is matched on one side or the other.